# Windows Batch script stops reading a file after a record has been written via IF in DO loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

Sometimes I think my  relationship with the Windows command line is weighted in favour of Stockholms syndrome over anthing else. I'm hoping someone else in this world of punishing stuff has an answer for me!

Here's the background and the problem statement: I have a quite large script that does stuff with a for loop that steps through a file searching for a record number, and changing the record while writing the records around in a nice sequential batch way, ie records are written up to the target record; a changed record is written; the remaining records are written. I needed to add a new action verb to the existing set, which requires an additional `IF` clause. It suddenly stopped writing out remaining records after the found record had been changed.  Couldn't find the answer.

So I started stripping away code until I reached this residual script. The `IF` clause in the `FOR/ in / DO` loop ... Leave it in, the script stalls after the written record as per the first sample below; leave it out, the `FOR` loop happily does it's thing, as per the second sample output. It gets stranger. Adding in script gives error messages, sometimes running through to completion, sometimes not ~ even a simple echo will give a parsing error. Placement in the script also seems to matter, which made debugging an absolute nightmare.

Clearly there is something that is triggering the command processor to quit the loop. SO I would pose the following two questions to the community:

1. What is causing the `FOR /in /DO` structure to stop processing records
2. What gives with the echo statements giving parsing errors? (echoing a variable name with a script line number, or just the number, for instance, is very low impact. )

Thanks. Code follows, any text file can be used as the second parameter, the first is a line number to action.

```
echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET _filein=%~2
SET _line=%1
set _cnt=0
:: _filein = any file, _line = the line to be inspected, _cnt = loop counter

:: in the loop: _record = line value, _msg= display message if line is found
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i IN ('type %_filein%') DO (
  SET _record=%%i
  SET /a _cnt+=1
  IF [!_cnt!]==[%_line%] (
    echo the line %_line% is !_record!
    set _msg=the line is !_record! at position !_cnt!
    goto sayrecord
  )
  echo not the line:
  :sayrecord
  echo !_cnt!- !_record!
)
:Xit
echo:
IF [%_msg%]==[] (
  echo: left out
) ELSE (
  echo: I'm in to see %_msg%
)

ENDLOCAL
exit /b
```

## **Test runs:**

*1. With the IF statement: (note parsing error statement)*

H>_a 3 _files.txt

```
H>echo off
not the line:
1- notes.bat
not the line:
2- notesqa.bat
the line 3 is bulkfiledelete.bat
3- bulkfiledelete.bat

line was unexpected at this time.

H>
```

---

*Without the IF:*

H>_a 3 _files.txt

```
H>echo off
not the line:
1- notes.bat
not the line:
2- notesqa.bat
not the line:
3- bulkfiledelete.bat
not the line:
4- CheckAdminRights.bat
not the line:
 :   :   :
not the line:
47- Reset connection 3 - renew.lnk
not the line:
48- ============

 left out

H>
```

Comment: Is it your intent to terminate the loop on the goto?  Maybe you should be using call instead?

Comment: [@jwdonaahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue) No, I want it to ammend a target record in a dataset. So write out records up to the target record, then write out an ammended record, then write out the remaining records. Without the `IF` statement, this is what the script does, with the `if` clause, it jumps out of the loop.

Comment: Then you probably want to use `call :sayrecord` instead of the goto.

Comment: [@jwdonaahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue), thanks, I could try that, and I do have other workarounds (such as multiple scripts). It would still be good to know why the `IF` clause  is causing the script to stop processing records. I would still need multiple `IF` clauses because there are different changes to the target record based on content in the live scripts.

Comment: [@Gerhard Barnard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard), no - I am still within the `DO'`loop as you can see when the `IF` clause is removed.

Comment: Does your record file contain any `!` perhaps?

Comment: You can't have labels inside of `for` loops.

Comment: Remove the invalid label and goto then move `echo not the line:` up a line and precede it with `else`.

Comment: The `if` clause causes the `goto` that always breaks out of the `for` loop.  It's just the way that cmd processes for loops.  Get rid of the `goto`.

Comment: Also, don't use the goofy `::` labels for comments.  They aren't universally useful because they cause problems in some scripts.  Always us REM statements for comments, it will help preserve your hair-line.

Comment: [@SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) Thank you! That **absolutely** was the issue and the ammended sample script shows the correct way to handle it in the answer.

Comment: [@jwdonaahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue), I prefer absolutely clean script, this was just for asking the Q ~ in my active scripts there are no remarks at all. I put echos at the bottom of the script which explains what is going on where needed, and which explains variables, parameters etc. A header jump (on `/h') lets me see it when (a) I want to use the script and need memory refreshed and (b) for when maint is done. Take you point about the goofiness, though ;-)

Comment: hard to say without seing the txt file, but repacing `IF [!_cnt!]==[%_line%]` with `IF "!_cnt!"=="%_line%"` could make you happy. (same issue with each `if` statement)

Comment: [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan), thanks for the reply. The file is just a bare `dir /b` list of file names. The issue was identified by  [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) as the  use of `goto :label` as a catchall to fire the file write.

Comment: anyway - switch to the quoted `if` syntax to avoid syntax errors in case there are file names with spaces (and you can never be sure there won't be any).

Comment: sorry [@Gerhard Barnard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard), I missed your comment ~ no there were no '!' in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have a code block that works thanks to [@jwdonaahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue) for the initial clue; and [@SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) for the problem statement.

The `:label` is the problem here, although it works in many other production scripts it clearly is problematic. Instead of a script that drops to the bottom of the loop for processing, putting in an `IF` clause for each use case is what is needed.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET _filein=%~2
SET _line=%1
set _cnt=0
:: _filein = any file, _line = the line to be inspected, _cnt = loop counter

:: in the loop: _record = line value, _msg= display message if line is found
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i IN ('type %_filein%') DO (
  SET _record=%%i
  SET /a _cnt+=1
  IF [!_cnt!]==[%_line%] (
    echo the line %_line% is !_record!
    set "_msg=the line is !_record! at position !_cnt!"
    echo not the line:
    CALL :sayrecord
  )
  IF [!_cnt!] neq [%_line%] CALL :sayrecord
)
:Xit
echo:
IF [%_msg%]==[] (
  echo: left out
) ELSE (
  echo: I'm in to see %_msg%
)

ENDLOCAL
exit /b

:sayrecord
echo !_cnt!- !_record!
exit /b
```

i.e. to solve my problem,

1. add an `IF` clause for each action verb;
2. end with an `IF' clause which wraps the records that must be written unchanged

I'll also go through all the scripts and do a maint on them!

Answer (score 1):

Given that your stated intent was to replace the content of `%2` on line `%1`, you don't need delayed expansion or to `set` all of those variables:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%I In ('Type "%~2"^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""')Do @If "%%I"=="[%~1%" (Echo Inserted line content)Else Echo=%%J
@Pause
```

*You would modify the content after `Echo`  and before `)` to the replacement line content, and the last line is added just to ensure that you can read the output.*

---

**[Edit /]**
If you wanted to ask the end user for confirmation of the change before doing so, you could expand your code to incorporate that:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%I In ('Type "%~2"^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""')Do @If "%%I"=="[%~1" ("%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Replace %%J with new content"&If ErrorLevel 2 (Echo=%%J)Else Echo Inserted line content)Else Echo=%%J
@Pause
```

Comment: Thanks [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo), great reply. My background notes to the problem are key to the solution set, though: there are a number of use cases that require separate handling.  In the single requirement use case your script is beatifully elegant and I'm going to use it going forward. Another one for the toolbox.

Comment: Also, in the script where the solution is required, the user must check before and after image and confirm the change.

Comment: @ilinkcs, Unfortunately we can only provide solutions based upon the information you provide in your question, _(and any subsequent comments not added appropriately to that question)_. I have however, added an example under **[Edit /]** to allow for the end user to confirm replacement before doing so.

Comment: actually, you know what? that piece of script allows one to pull the user interaction and verb / message build up **before** the loop saving the temp file creation and initial record writing. This also simplifies user backout. I'm going to implement the answer I posted now as a workaround, and then re-do the whole block using your snippet: it's a really cool outcome.

Comment: tbf, my original request was for an explanation: _"1. What is causing the FOR /in /DO structure to stop processing records"_  , but the replies expanded it into root cause which gave me (amongst many) your response which is going to improve the overall batch. There are 5 action use cases to handle each with variation, and two validation backouts, so one or two of them have multiple interactions. Thanks for the great response and effort. much appreciated.